# Cannot set property '$submitted' of undefined error - Jasmine AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a function of my controller, Inside that function I trying to set the $submitted property of form like following.

```
$scope.submitForm=function(){                     
     $scope.form.$submitted = false;
     $scope.done = true;     
     // code
};
```

When I call this function from my test like:

```
it('should be called', function () {
     contactUsController.submitForm();
     expect(contactUsController.submitForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '$submitted' of undefined
```

Comment: $scope.form = {};

Try that before the $submitted line.

Comment: Are you sure you have a <form name="form"> in your html?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel yes.

Comment: Then try to put $scope.form = {}; as @rrd said, but put in the beginning of the controller...

Comment: Ya , its working now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment helped, add below code in the beginning of the controller:

```
$scope.form = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `$scope.form` as an object before you can set properties on it. Otherwise you are setting a property on a non existant object and hence get an error of `can't set property of undefined`.

Just edit your code like this:

```
$scope.submitForm=function(){      
     $scope.form = {};               
     $scope.form.$submitted = false;
     $scope.done = true;     
     // code
};
```